Можно ли преобразовать переменную Switch в переменную boolean (Android Studio)
Как мне правильно преобразовать что бы получилось что то типа этого:
Switch switch1 = findViewById(R.id.b1Switch);
boolean b = switch1;


"Превратить" нельзя.
Можно получить состояние этого контрола его методом isChecked()
Switch switch1 = findViewById(R.id.b1Switch);
boolean b = switch1.isChecked();

Прежде чем задавать подобные вопросы потрудитесь почитать документацию к используемым классам.
